# scrape paginated content with scrapy and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

i'm using selenium with scrapy for scraping a website that has ajax content. 
first of all, i cant simulate the ajax request because of "csrf" thing.
and the main question, here is the link i want to scrape:

```
https://lastsecond.ir/hotels
```

the pattern for this site's url is like this :

```
https://lastsecond.ir/hotels?page=1

https://lastsecond.ir/hotels?page=2

https://lastsecond.ir/hotels?page=3

.... 

https://lastsecond.ir/hotels?page=230
```

the content produced by ajax so i have to use selenium to wait a little in the browser, but i cant move through pages and get the all content! i just get the first page content, i dont get any errors. 
here is my spider code :

```
class HotelsSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'hotels'
    allowed_domains = ['lastsecond.ir']
    start_urls = ['http://lastsecond.ir/hotels']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'/hotels\?page=[0-9]/'), 
        callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(HotelsSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe')

    def parse_item(self, response):
        self.driver.get("http://lastsecond.ir/hotels?page=1")
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "panel1"))
        )
        response = TextResponse(url=response.url, 
            body=self.driver.page_source, encoding='utf-8')
        hotel = ItemLoader(item=HotelItem(), response=response)
        hotel.add_css('hotel_name', '#panel1 h2.semimedium-font-size 
            a::text')
        return hotel.load_item()
```

every page have a ajax request and it does not have a "next" link, its numbered pagination. 
my main problem is i just get the first page content !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Token` is in `http://lastsecond.ir/hotels` in `JavaScript` code, ie.

```
var csrftoken = 'P7E5Txa5GGmMdJaEf6Y99RsD24vlzD74zEqKg83f';
```

so you can use standard string functions to get it.

If you have token then you can create `POST` requests to `http://lastsecond.ir/hotels/ajax` using `FormRequest()` and you don't need `Selenium`

In `FormRequest()` use `dont_filter=True` because it will execute the same url many times and scrapy normally skips duplicated urls.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import scrapy
#from scrapy.commands.view import open_in_browser
import json

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'myspider'

    #allowed_domains = []

    start_urls = ['https://lastsecond.ir/hotels']

    #def start_requests(self):
    #    self.url_template = http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/{}/page/{}/
    #    self.tags = ['love', 'inspirational', 'life', 'humor', 'books']
    #    self.pages = 10
    # 
    #    for tag in self.tags:
    #        for page in range(self.pages):
    #            url = self.url_template.format(tag, page)
    #            yield scrapy.Request(url)

    def parse(self, response):
        print('url:', response.url)

        html = response.body_as_unicode()

        start = html.find("var csrftoken = '")
        start = start + len(b"var csrftoken = '")
        end = html.find("';" , start)

        self.csrftoken = html[start:end]

        print('csrftoken:', self.csrftoken)

        yield self.create_ajax_request('1')

    def create_ajax_request(self, page):
        ''' 
        subfunction can't use `yield, it has to `return` Request to `parser`
        and `parser` can use `yield`
        '''

        print('yield page:', page)

        url = 'https://lastsecond.ir/hotels/ajax'

        headers = {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': self.csrftoken,
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        }

        params = {
            'filter_score': '',
            'sort': 'reviewed_at',
            'duration': '0',
            'page': page,
            'base_location_id': '1',
        }

        return scrapy.FormRequest(url, 
            callback=self.parse_details, 
            formdata=params, 
            headers=headers, 
            dont_filter=True, 
        )

        #open_in_browser(response)

        # save JSON in separated file
        #number = response.url.split('/')[-1]
        #filename = 'page-{}.json'.format(number)
        #with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        #   f.write(response.body)

        # convert JSON into Python's dictionary
        #data = json.loads(response.text)

        # download files
        #for href in response.css('img::attr(href)').extract():
        #   url = response.urljoin(src)
        #   yield {'file_urls': [url]}

        # download images and convert to JPG
        #for src in response.css('img::attr(src)').extract():
        #   url = response.urljoin(src)
        #   yield {'image_urls': [url]}

        #item = {'url': '...', 'title': '...'}
        #yield self.Request(url, meta={'item': item}, callback=self.parse_details)

    def parse_details(self, response):
        print('url:', response.url)

        data = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())

        current = data['pagination']['current']
        last = data['pagination']['last']

        print('page:', current, '/', last)

        print('keys:', data.keys())
        print('keys[hotels]:', data['hotels'][0].keys())
        print('pagination:', data['pagination'])

        for hotel in data['hotels']:
            print('title_en:', hotel['title_en'])
            yield hotel

        if current != last:
            yield self.create_ajax_request( str(int(current) + 1) )

# --- it runs without project and saves in `output.csv` ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',

    # save in file as CSV, JSON or XML
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',     # csv, json, xml
    'FEED_URI': 'output.csv', # 

    # download files to `FILES_STORE/full`
    # it needs `yield {'file_urls': [url]}` in `parse()`
    #'ITEM_PIPELINES': {'scrapy.pipelines.files.FilesPipeline': 1},
    #'FILES_STORE': '/path/to/valid/dir',

    # download images and convert to JPG
    # it needs `yield {'image_urls': [url]}` in `parse()`
    #'ITEM_PIPELINES': {'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1},
    #'IMAGES_STORE': '/path/to/valid/dir',
})
c.crawl(MySpider)
c.start()
```

Part of result on screen. All data are saved in `output.csv`.

```
page: 1

keys: dict_keys(['hotels', 'pagination', 'grades', 'locations', 'scores'])
keys[hotels]: dict_keys(['id', 'title_fa', 'title_en', 'link', 'logo_link', 'decorated_grade', 'location', 'rank', 'is_recommended_percent', 'decorated_score', 'reviews_count'])

title_en: Heliya Kish hotel
title_en: Amara Prestige Elite
title_en: All Seasons Hotel
title_en: Hotel Grand Unal
title_en: Marmaray hotel
title_en: Nova Plaza Taksim Square
title_en: Flora Grand Hotel
title_en: Boulevard Autograph Collection hotel
title_en: Alfa Istanbul hotel
title_en: Ramada Hotel & Suites Istanbul Merter
title_en: Sabena hotel
title_en: Taksim Gonen
title_en: Fame Residence Lara & SPA
title_en: Palazzo Donizetti Hotel
title_en: Twin Towers hotel
title_en: Grand Hotel de Pera hotel
title_en: Grand Hotel Halic
title_en: Grand Pamir hotel
title_en: St George hotel
title_en: The Royal Paradise hotel

page: 2

keys: dict_keys(['hotels', 'pagination', 'grades', 'locations', 'scores'])
keys[hotels]: dict_keys(['id', 'title_fa', 'title_en', 'link', 'logo_link', 'decorated_grade', 'location', 'rank', 'is_recommended_percent', 'decorated_score', 'reviews_count'])

title_en: Radisson Royal moscow hotel
title_en: Avenue hotel
title_en: jamshid esfahan hotel
title_en: Aquatek hotel
title_en: Adalya Elite Lara
title_en: Federal Kuala Lumpur hotel
title_en: Feronya Hotel
title_en: Dolabauri Tbilisi hotel
title_en: Limak Limra hotel
title_en: Urban Boutique Hotel
title_en: Doubletree Hilton Piyalepasa hotel
title_en: Ferman Hilal hotel
title_en: Grand Oztanik Hotel
title_en: Lara Family Club hotel
title_en: Swissotel The Bosphorus
title_en: Berjaya Times Square hotel
title_en: Gardenia hotel
title_en: Rixos Sungate
title_en: Jumeirah Emirates Towers hotel
title_en: Kervansaray Lara Hotel
```

Comment: Thank You for this complete answer, it works now. do you have a reference to understand this requests better ? i still dont know how to send this requests .

Comment: this code became a kind of default to my scrapy ... when i try to generate a new spider with "scrapy genspider", first this code runs and then my code executes. how can i solve this ?

Comment: I created standalone code which doesn't need project. If you use it in project then don't use `CrawlerProcess()` and all below `"it runs without project"`

Comment: to understands HTTP requests I use DevTools in Chrome/Firefox - tab "Network" (for JavaScript requests see "Network > XHR"). To understand class `Request` in scrapy I read documentation for [Requests and Responses](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html)

Comment: wikipedia [Hypertext Transfer Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol)

Comment: you can also test requests on [httpbin.org](https://httpbin.org). Or use local proxy server like [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) (wikipedia: [Charles Proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Proxy)) to see all requests sends from browser - if you sent `proxy` in browser's settings. Or more complicated python's [mitm proxy](http://docs.mitmproxy.org/en/latest/mitmproxy.html) or [Wireshark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark)

Comment: when i try to use it in project and delete the parts you say, i get this error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "D:\Python\lastsecond\lastsecond\spiders\hotels.py", line 97, in parse_details
    data = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Comment: it means you get empty response (`None`) and `json` can't convert `None` into python's dictionary. Use `print(respnse.body)` to see what you get. Did you tried to run it as standalone script ? Did you get the same error ? Server may blocks you.

Comment: as a standalone project, it works correctly. the result of printing the response.body was some html code, i think its a error page. also my request status is 302: `2017-12-25 07:22:24 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://lastsecond.ir> from <POST https://lastsecond.ir/hotels/ajax>`

Comment: maybe you forgot some params in POST request and then it redirect (code 302) to page with error message. You can create new question with new problem or eventually append problem to current question but don't change original question.